# Junit double quote comparison

Tags: junit, junit4, junit5

How to write testcase for the below method?

Method will take integer as a parameter and returns double quoted value.
ex: 14 is the input and "14" is the output.

```
public static String getIntegerToString(Integer number) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        buffer.append('"').append(number).append('"');
        return buffer.toString();
    }
```

I am not getting the way to write the test cases. Please help me

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Tried this, but no luck.  assertEquals("\"14"\", FuzzBizzImpl.getIntegerToString(14));

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
@Test
void test() {
    int num = 14;
    assertEquals("\"" + num + "\"", FuzzBizzImpl.getIntegerToString(num));
}
```